# combine values from different rows into single row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm combining multiple rows into a single row based on a value in the far left column.
This is the table I'm working with:

```
Example1    1   2                   1
Example1    1   2   3               2
Example1            3   4           3
Example1                4   5       4
Example1    2               5   6   5
Example1                        6   6
Example1                            7
Example2    7   8                   8
Example2        8   9               9
Example2            9   10          10
Example2                10  11      11
Example2                    11  12  12
Example2                        12  13
Example2                            14
Example2                            15
Example2                            16
Example2                            17
Example3                            18
Example4    13  14                  19
Example4        14  15              20
Example4            15  16          21
Example4                16  17      22
Example4                    17  18  23
Example4                        18  24
Example4                            25
Example4                            26
Example4                            27
Example4                            28
```

Here is what I'm getting:

```
Example1        2   3   4   5   6
Example2        8   9   10  11  12
Example3        8   9   10  11  12
Example4        14  15  16  17  18
```

Here's what I want:

```
Example1        2   3   4   5   6
Example2        8   9   10  11  12
Example3                        
Example4        14  15  16  17  18
```

Here is the code:

```
Sub sprt()

    Dim h As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim MyArray(8) As String
    Dim MyArray2(100, 8) As String

    a = 0
    b = 0

    For i = 1 To 28
    For j = 1 To 7

    Sheets("Sheet6").Activate

    If Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
        MyArray(j) = Cells(i, j).value
    End If

    Next

    If i = 1 Then b = 1

    If i > 1 Then

    If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1) Then b = b + 1

    End If

    For j = 1 To 7
        MyArray2(b, j) = MyArray(j)

    Next

    Next
    For i = 1 To b

    For j = 1 To 7

    a = 10

    Cells(i, j + a) = MyArray2(i, j)

    Next

    Next
```

What can I change to get the result I want?

Comment: Add `Erase Myarray` after loading it into myarray2.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @ScottCarner suggestion, i have shuffled your code and tried, it worked fine.

```
Sub sprt()

    Dim h As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim MyArray(8) As String
    Dim MyArray2(100, 8) As String
    a = 0
    b = 0
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    For i = 1 To 28

        If i = 1 Then b = 1
        If i > 1 Then
            If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
                b = b + 1
                Erase MyArray
            End If
        End If

        For j = 1 To 7

            If Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
                MyArray(j) = Cells(i, j).Value
            End If

        Next

        For j = 1 To 7
            MyArray2(b, j) = MyArray(j)
        Next
    Next

    For i = 1 To b
        For j = 1 To 7
            a = 10
            Cells(i, j + a) = MyArray2(i, j)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```